# multidomain configuration for flask application

Tags: python, flask

I need configure flask application to handle requests with any host in HTTP header

If some fqdn is specified in SERVER_NAME I have 404 error if request goes with any other domain.
How should be defined SERVER_NAME in configuration?

How can be requested/routed/blueprint-ed HTTP hostname?

Answer (score 0):

Use `app.run(host='0.0.0.0')` if you want flask to accept any host name.

Comment: your answer is about binding server to all ip. 
What i need - handle request for any domain (http header 'Host'). Hostname is passed as parameter to create_app not to app.run

Comment: sorry for error in prev comment: 
'passed as parameter to create_app' => 'is a part of application configuration (config['SERVER_NAME'])'

Comment: AFAIK, that is the same thing. When requesting `whatever.com`, browser determines IP address (e.g. `123.123.123.123`) and sends request to `123.123.123.123`. The request, contains host name `whatever.com` in HTTP headers. Flask is going to receive that request and compare the host from HTTP headers to what was passed as `host` argument. If flask was started as `host='0.0.0.0'`, that will work, if it was started as `host='whatever.com'`, it will still work, but if it was started as `host='somethingelse.org'` then it will refuse the request, even though `somethingelse.org` may resolve to same IP

Comment: sorry but i think you are wrong. argument host in app.run determine ip where web server should listen to. host=0.0.0.0 mean listen at ALL interfaces.
Parameter in config determine  hostnames which should be handled by our application (routes in flask more precisely). 
I think i just found solution. I just removed SERVER_NAME from config and it's work for all hostnames

Comment: Maybe I am wrong. If you have a solution, please be kind and post it as answer to your question. Others will be interested to know what exactly you did.

Answer (score 0):

To allow any domain name just remove 'SERVER_NAME' from application config

Comment: unfortunately i need create DIFFERENT application (with different configs) depending on hostname. But request is not available until application is created